# python Dictionary for printing inventory if value is less than input

Tags: python, python-3.x

A computer store manages its laptop inventory by using Python dictionaries. Each dictionary entry has the string name of a specific computer laptop model as a key and its integer quantity in inventory as its corresponding value.

An example:

```
d = {"MS Surface":47, "HP Laptop Probook":144, "MacBook Pro":23, "Dell Laptop XPS": 10, "Asus Chromebook": 20}
```

Define a function low_inventory(laptop_dict, threshold) which returns a list of the names of all entries in laptop inventory laptop_dict whose quantities are less than (<) the int threshold.

Example: calling your function as  total_items(d,47) should return :

```
['MacBook Pro', 'Dell Laptop XPS', 'Asus Chromebook']
```

```
def low_inventory(laptop_dict, threshold):
    for akey in laptop_dict.keys():
        if laptop_dict[akey] < threshold:
                ----
```

Could you please suggest how to do this. I am new to python and struggling with output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filter

```
value = filter(lambda x: dict[x] < 3, keys)
```

And other iteration functions

http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a list, so you could start by defining one. Something like:

```
low_inv = []
```

Then in your loop `append()` the key (which is the name of the computer in this case) to that list if the inventory is low. Then return it:

```
d = {"MS Surface":47, "HP Laptop Probook":144, "MacBook Pro":23, "Dell Laptop XPS": 10, "Asus Chromebook": 20}

def total_items(laptop_dict, threshold):
    low_inv = []                           # new list
    for akey in laptop_dict.keys():
        if laptop_dict[akey] < threshold:
            low_inv.append(akey)           # append to it
    return low_inv                         # return it

total_items(d,47)

#['MacBook Pro', 'Dell Laptop XPS', 'Asus Chromebook']
```

This can also be done as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which creates a list in one go without the explicit loop:

```
def total_items(laptop_dict, threshold):
    return [akey for akey, inv in laptop_dict.items() if inv < threshold]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `d.items()` to iterate over the dictionary given the key and value. Try something like this:

```
def low_inventory(laptop_dict, threshold):
    low = []
    for key, value in laptop_dict.items():
        if value < threshold:
            low.append(key)
    return low
```